# GO programming, blocking read function on a reader event

Tags: go, networking, chat

I am a beginner in Go programming and I am confused about a problem about bufio readers.
I'm programming a kind of chat client who must display and send our messages in live time. But messages that I receive are not displayed until I press enter in my terminal.
After few tests, it seems to be my "inputListener()" function being the problem because, if I put it after reading messages from server, messages from server are displaying first.
I supposed that the Read function may blocked my loop until it get a '\n' or something like that.

Here is my code:

```
package main
import "os"
import "strconv"
import "net"
import "bufio"

/*Recovery our input message into a buffer*/
func inputListener()([] byte){
    buf := make([]byte, 512)
    readerInput := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    _, err := readerInput.Read(buf)
    if err != nil{
        panic("Error reading input.")
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    return buf
}


func main(){
if len(os.Args) != 3{
    println("Usage: ",os.Args[0], " <host> <port>\n")
    os.Exit(0)
}

//Recovery the port.
port, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2])
if err != nil{
  panic("Error during the port recovery\n")
  os.Exit(0)
}
println(port)

/*Join the adresse*/
addr := os.Args[1] + ":" + strconv.Itoa(port)
println(addr)

/*  sources -- https://golang.org/pkg/net/  */

conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr)
if err != nil{
    panic("Error connecting " + addr)
    os.Exit(0)
}


buf := make([]byte, 512)
t := make([]byte, 512)

for {

    /*Receive data from server*/
    size, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error reading output.")
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    if size >= 0{
        print(string(buf[0:size]))
    }

    /*Data we need to send*/
    t = inputListener()
    if len(t) >= 0{
        conn.Write(t)
    }
} 

conn.Close()
}
```

I need to press enter per messages received :/

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: What is the question?   Notes about the code: some tests are not needed because len(slice) is always greater than zero; there's no need to call os.Exit after panic;  the program may lose input data because `inputListener` discards the bufio.Reader.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! The question is about, is there an other way to catch data from server into a buffer, because those lines:`readerInput := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
            _, err := readerInput.Read(buf)` seems to be blocking my loop until I press Enter. It is problematic because it is note a live chat in this case. (Excuse me if it is not clear, i'm beginning in both, Go and Networking).Thanks, 3t13nne.

Comment: Oops, len(slice) is always *greater than or equal to zero*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You be try something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

/*Recovery our input message into a buffer*/
func inputListener() []byte {
    buf := make([]byte, 512)
    readerInput := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    _, err := readerInput.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error reading input.")
    }
    return buf
}

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 3 {
        println("Usage: ", os.Args[0], " <host> <port>\n")
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    //Recovery the port.
    port, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2])
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error during the port recovery\n")
    }
    println(port)

    /*Join the adresse*/
    addr := os.Args[1] + ":" + strconv.Itoa(port)
    println(addr)

    /*  sources -- https://golang.org/pkg/net/  */

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error connecting " + addr)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, conn)

    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        p, err := r.ReadSlice('\n')
        if err != nil {
            panic("Error reading output.")
        }
        conn.Write(p)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working PER-FECT-LY ! But still got few question if I do not bother you, why should I prefer use defer in place of just close the protocol at the end of the program ? What does mean "go" before io.Copy ? Should I don't use the Read() function? Thanks !